# Acentuação + $http.get

Tags: php, ajax, string, angularjs, acentuação

Estou tendo dificuldades em fazer uma chamada Ajax usando AngularJS pelo motivo de que as strings que possuem acentos estão retornando nulas, como resposta à chamada, meu PHP está retornando um JSON `json_encode($data)`, e ao receber a resposta estou transformando o JSON em um array `angular.fromJson(data)`, assim como era no meu server-side.

Meu cabeçalho PHP está configurado `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true)`, quando retorno o `var_dump` posso ver todas as strings, acentuadas ou não. O problema está com o JSON, penso que a solução seja um *header* adequado para o meu *request*.

Este é meu script:

```
$http.get("busca_tamanhos.php", {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json, text/plain'}}).success(function(data){
    $scope.tamanhos = angular.fromJson(data);
    $window.console.log(data);
});
```

PS: consigo visualizar strings não acentuadas, e minha base de dados é ISO-8859-1.

Comment: JSON é utf-8 por definição, você não pode usar esse charset que está tentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON só trabalha com UTF-8, tentar montar uma string JSON usando símbolos incompatíveis com essa codificação fará com que a string seja convertida em `null` pela função `json_encode()` do PHP.

Certifique-se que toda string na estrutura sendo passada para o `json_encode()` seja primeiro convertida pra UTF-8 usando a função `utf8_encode()`.

```
function iso88591_json_encode($data)
{
    array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$value) { if (is_string($value)) $value = utf8_encode($value); });
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Mas poderia me explicar somente o que a função array_walk_recursive faz?

Comment: e também o porque daquele '&' antes da variável dentro dos parâmetros da função

Comment: A função `array_walk_recursive()` vai executar aquela função em todos os valores da array, e se tiver mais arrays dentro da array, vai entrar nelas e executar nos valores delas também. Aquele símbolo serve pra fazer com que alterando o valor de `$value` dentro da função, o valor seja mudado no caller também.

Answer (score -1):

Yuri, se você está publicando texto em porguês, e está usando `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true)` já tem algo errado (!). É preciso que o programador assuma compromisso com a sua língua, e questione as normas da empresa, ou mesmo do cliente, se houver alguma recomendação para não usar UTF-8.

### Programadores da língua portuguesa: o nosso charset é o UTF8!

Resumidamente, esse fato, para programadores PHP, acarreta dois cuidados:

1. Páginas, dados, scripts PHP, tudo deve ser codificado em UTF8. Desconfie da arquitetura, da biblioteca, do ambiente, do que for que não estiver representando o português em em UTF-8.
2. Fique atento ao PHP, ele não é "nativamente UTF8", isso pode causar transtornos. Para superar esse problema, confira as [dicas e detalhes nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186).