# Problema ao usar substr em texto com PHP

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres

Ao usar `substr` em uma variável com texto, ele esta retornando um caracter especial "�" alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$the_str = substr($excerpt, 0, 335);
echo $the_str . '...';
```

Comment: Suspeito que sua string seja multibyte. Nesse caso você poderia usar mb_substr. Pode postar o trecho relevante do código (e uma string de exemplo) para confirmarmos?

Comment: @bfavaretto, consegui utilizando mb_substr, porém qual a diferença, de substr para mb_substr?

Comment: Postei uma resposta com a explicação.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Obrigado!

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78308/por-que-deveriamos-utilizar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-que-come%C3%A7am-por-mb

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sua string provavelmente está codificada como UTF-8, o que é desejável, pois assim você consegue representar uma quantidade imensa de caracteres especiais. Em UTF-8, certos caracteres, incluindo todos os acentuados, ocupam mais de um byte. Porém a função `substr` considera que cada caracter ocupa somente um byte. O que está acontecendo é que o `substr` está cortando um caractere no meio, pegando apenas o primeiro byte dele. Quando o browser vai exibir a saída do `substr`, esse byte avulso é considerado um caractere inválido.

A solução é usar a função [`mb_substr`](https://www.php.net/mb_substr), que foi projetada para lidar com caracteres multibyte:

```
$the_str = mb_substr($excerpt, 0, 335);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, foi de grande ajuda sua resposta!

Comment: O problema é que ele está usando PHP: por que o `substr` normal não dá suporte a UTF-8?

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues O motivo técnico é que as funções padrão de manipulação de strings assumem que a codificação usa apenas um byte por caractere. O motivo dessa escolha de design deve ser histórico, quando o php foi criado o utf8 ainda não era usado como padrão na web.

Comment: E eles criam outra função por compatibilidade ao invés de alterar a antiga, causando problemas aos desenvolvedores. Daí surgem dúzias de funções com a mesma utilização mas para situações diferentes.

Comment: E de que adianta ficar aqui chorando as pitangas por causa disso? É assim que a linguagem é, se não gosta/consegue usar dessa forma, procure outra. Não existe linguagem perfeita.

Comment: @bfavaretto, geralmente eu passo o quarto parâmetro que é utf-8. Não é necessário?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Você pode estar isso globalmente com `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`, se UTF8 já não for o padrão do servidor. Mas sem ver isso realmente é mais seguro passar como último parâmetro.

Comment: @bfavaretto, pelo manual, o terceiro parâmetro é `mb_detect_encode`. Ou seja, se nada for passado, o encoding da string (e não o pré-definido) é detectado. Pelo menos é o que eu entendi.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos, só faltou mandar ir programar em `Python`. Brincadeira

Comment: @wallace será que estamos olhando o mesmo manual?!

Comment: Esquece essa palhacada @bfavaretto. O Manual me confundiu - mais do que ajuda :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters  então, veja que não tem detecção, ele pega a codificação multibyte padrão

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo. Na verdade, se quiser detectar a codificação tem que fazer assim: `mb_substr($str, 0, 3, mb_detect_encoding($str))`.

Answer (score 10):

[Esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8429/4186) lembra que no PHP não basta usar a função correta, que, bem sugerida pelo @bfavaretto, é a [`mb_substr()`](https://www.php.net/mb_substr) no lugar da `substr()`: precisamos também configurar o PHP corretamente para as funções *multibyte* não causarem surpresas.

O que sugiro como configuração, **a usar sempre no Português**, é

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_BR.UTF8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF8'); 
mb_regex_encoding('UTF8');
```

### Usar UTF-8 e funções compativeis para tudo!

O [ISO Latim I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (formalmente *ISO-8859-1*) foi aposentado anos atrás, o [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/) vem sugerindo uso de UTF-8 (ver [RFC-3629](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt)) em todas as recomendações.

Da mesma forma, para sites brasileiros, a recomendação [e-PING](http://eping.governoeletronico.gov.br/) é o **padrão charset UTF-8**...
O *"padrão de fato"*, mais popular pelos sites minimamente sérios e "antenados" da língua portuguesa: idem, é UTF-8. Se conferir grandes portais brasileiros ou mesmo protugueses, vai ver logo no header HTML que o padrão adotado é UTF8 (ex. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"../>` do código-fonte da [UOL](http://www.uol.com.br/)).

### Legados históricos

Quem trabalha com PHP lida com dois legados históricos que causam ainda hoje certa confusão, e por isso acho importante relembra-los:

1. O *charset*  ISO-Latin-1 foi durante muito tempo no Brasil e em Portugual o "padrão oficial" para páginas HTML, arquivos TXT, XML, SGML, etc. É natural, porque o UTF-8 veio depois do ISO-Latin, e justamente ele abriga na sua estrutura, sem alterações, como [Bloco Unicode de Suplemento Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)).

   PS: A Microsoft desde o Windows 3.x, para isolar seus usuários de qualquer iniciativa de padronisação, sempre forçou o "ISO Latin Microsoft" (conhecido como  "[código Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)"), e ainda hoje alguns programadores e web-designers brasileiros publicam HTML com esse *charset*. É um insulto às normas internacionais e ao usuário.
2. O PHP tentou superar essa coisa chata de funções string duplicadas — uma biblioteca `mb_*` para charsets tipo UTF-8 de tamanho variável (multibyte) e outra charsets ISO 8 bits fixos — [com a proposta do PHP6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#PHP_6_and_Unicode), mas nunca conseguiu (apesar de linguagens como o [Python](http://www.python.org) terem feito isso muito tempo antes). Isso causa transtorno (estamos aqui perdendo tempo com essa pergunta!) até os dias de hoje para os programadores da língua portuguesa.

---

### Onde mais tem "pegadinha" para UTF8?

#### Regular expressions

Mais uma vez a multiplicidade de opções para fazer a mesma coisa no PHP, causa certa confusão. Eu já trabalhei bastante com *regular expressions* e tenho plena convicção de que a melhor (mais potente aceita como padrão nas demais linguagens) biblioteca é a [PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions). Nunca precisei usar as [funções multibyte "mb_ereg_*"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php). A [família `preg_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) dá conta do recado. Basta ficarmos atentos a dois detalhes,

- Usar o modificador `/u` quando for usar acento ou caracter especial na própria regular expression.
- (ver abaixo discussão) Seu script PHP precisa estar em UTF8 para entender sua regular expression em UTF8.

#### Contagem de palavras

A função [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php), como outras tantas do PHP, tem algumas falhas para o "caso geral" de UTF8... [Veja discussão aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316871/287948).

#### Seus scripts PHP... São UTF8?

Outro problema comum é o seu próprio script de PHP, que precisa estar também em UTF8(!). Confira com algum editor sério e confiável (jamais o NotePad do Windows!), como por exemplo [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) ou [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/).

Idem bases de dados, arquivos XML, etc. Precisa estar tudo no mesmo *charset*, e, fácil: basta sempre configurar tudo  com o "padrão universal", que é o UTF8.

Comment: Ótima resposta!

Answer (score 3):

O php coloca esse carácter estranho automaticamente quando ele não reconhece o conjunto de carácter que este carácter pertence. Para resolver o problema você precisa transformar sua string em **utf8 padrão universal de caracteres**

Tente usar na string `utf8_encode($sua_string);`

Para mais detalhes http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php

Ou tente:

```
$string= mb_convert_encoding(utf8_encode($sua_string), 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: se eu adicionar utf8_encode na string ele retorna o texto assim "Eu jÃ¡ falei aqui da compostagem, que Ã© a transformaÃ§Ã£o de restos de comida em adubo, uma forma de diminuir o lixo orgÃ¢nico e cuidar melhor de suas plantas. Hoje eu trago outra dica que tambÃ©m ajuda a deixar o solo mais rico em nutrientes. Se vocÃª tem um jardim ou um quintal na sua casa, tente deixar as folhas e Â flores que Â..."

Comment: entendi, vou editar a resposta

Comment: O problema persiste, consegui resolver usando mb_substr no lugar de substr.