# Criar ficheiro CSV a partir de PHP

Tags: php, csv

Quero criar um ficheiro XSV a partir de PHP. O que quero é poder criar colunas e dar cor de fundo a um elemento por exemplo. Tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

outputCSV(array(
    array("name 1", "age 1", "city 1"),
    array("name 2", "age 2", "city 2"),
    array("name 3", "age 3", "city 3")
));

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

O ficheiro é bem gerado. O que é gerado fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu quero que fique assim (tudo dividido por coluna e se possível uma cor de fundo):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma API que possa usar?

Comment: Testei com o libreOffice 4.x os valores vieram nas colunas certas sem a cor de fundo.No SOen tem uma [lista de outra libs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel) que manipulam `.xls`

Comment: @perdeu o phpexcel seria uma boa opção, mas tenho que criar mesmo o ficheiro em CSV

Comment: Já tentou retirar o enclosure? `fputcsv($output, $row, ',', ''); `

Comment: @Jader pode explicar melhor? como meteu dá erro

Comment: @pc_oc olhe o comentário que coloquei em sua resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei por fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$table = 'nome_tabela';
$outstr = NULL;

header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=cars-models.csv");

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("bd",$conn);

// Query database to get column names  
$result = mysql_query("show columns from $table",$conn);
// Write column names
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $outstr.= $row['Field'].';';
}  
$outstr = substr($outstr, 0, -1)."\n";

// Query database to get data
$result = mysql_query("select * from $table",$conn);
// Write data rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $outstr.= join(';', $row)."\n";
}

echo $outstr;
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Ou seja, tenho que meter o ";" para criar uma coluna nova em vez de ter uma ",". Agora falta a questão de ter a linha com cor.

Comment: É impossível colorir arquivos CSV pois se trata de um arquivo texto com valores delimitados sem formatação (do inglês Comma-separated values). Se quiser formatação, tens que usar um .xls, .xlsx, .ods. **Ou seja, não ter cores é uma limitação do tipo de arquivo**.

Comment: Ok, obrigado! Tem que ser mesmo no formato csv porque o cliente assim quer. Em relação ao à codificação UTF-8, como posso resolver? Obrigado! @gmsantos

Comment: Qual problema você tem com UTF-8? não encontrei a dúvida na pergunta.

Comment: Sim, não perguntei isso na pergunta mas perguntei agora. É que da minha BD estão a vir dados com caracteres especiais e lembrei-me de perguntar. Qualquer maneira obrigado!

Comment: Pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8235/problema-ao-usar-substr-em-texto-com-php/8641#8641

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa apenas definir o campo Delimiter na função fputcsv

O CSV separa cada coluna através do caracter ;

Nesse caso você tem que definir o delimiter da função como sendo ";"

```
fputcsv($output, $row, ";");
```

O comando para executar o que deseja ficaria assim:

```
function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row, ";"); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```