# Como o programador/softhouse pode requerer de clientes e fornecedores o respeito ao UTF-8?

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres

(atualizado 2020) Ver manifesto pelo UTF-8, e todos os elementos da discussão que ainda haviam em torno do assunto até ~2015, em  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28404/4186

Do ponto de vista internacional e boas práticas, **UTF-8 é o padrão** [*de jure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure) (W3C, IETF, etc.) desde inicio dos anos 2000, e [*de facto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard) desde 2008 como mostra o "[gráfico da virada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)":

[image]

---

(mantendo abaixo por questões de registro histórico)

**Preâmbulos**: como já colocado [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8641/4186),  [nesta outra e diversas outras respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23807/por-que-ainda-se-usam-outras-codifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-al%C3%A9m-do-utf-8/28404#28404), o UTF-8 é um padrão *[de facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto)* e *[de jure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure)*. Governos, como o europeu e o brasileiro, e entidades democráticas, como o W3C, recomendam fortemente o uso do UTF-8. Os falantes do Português precisam tanto dos acentos quanto da interoperabilidade proporcionados pelo UTF-8.

Por que nós, analistas e programadores, não podemos exigir de nosso ambiente de trabalho, que se adote o padrão UTF-8?

**Pergunta**: *como as empresas de software e de informática poderiam exigir de seus clientes e fornecedores o intercambiar de dados em UTF-8?*

O que se busca com a pergunta são **recomendações de "boas práticas", técnicas,  gerenciais e comerciais**: como lidar com as pessoas que desconhecem ou que não dão o mesmo valor para o problema? Quais as práticas em uso hoje numa cadeia de suprimentos digital?

---

Alguns *cenários de exemplo*:

1. Requisitamos de um fornecedor "tudo em UTF8", é pouco delicado "bater o pé" exigindo UTF8?
2. Requisitamos de um cliente  "tudo em UTF8", posso pedir de novo quando ele ignorar o pedido, sem mesmo se justificar?
3. Estamos integrando todos os dados da empresa (cliente), e enfatizando que a interoperabilidade só será simples e viável se todos os subsistemas se expressem em UTF8... Aí metade não se expressa, e o custo de converter e testar tudo denovo vai lá pro alto... O que fazer?
4. Um colega, amigão, é responsável pela infra-estrutura (entre outras coisas é o único com permissão de instalar e reconfigurar os softwares dos PCs e do servidor)... No nosso departamento combinamos que tudo precisa ser UTF-8. Sistema operacional de cada PC, cada IDE (ex. Eclipse), cada compilador, cada base de dados... Tudo garantindo "*DEFAULT* UTF-8" ou manualmente configurando como UTF-8. Mas o colega responsável nitidamente fez corpo mole, e estamos longe de conseguir isso. O que fazer?
5. Como dar os primeiros passos para mudar a cultura do "deixa pra lá essa coisa de codificação", impregnada em nós e a nossa volta?

---

### NOTAS

Naturalmente, não se pode exigir de quem não tem como gerar saídas UTF-8, mas sabemos que 90% dos casos de configuração *default* de um produto nacional, nacionalizado ou "localizado", podem adotar UTF-8. Mais ainda, quando se fala de intercâmbio de dados, ou seja, formatos tais como XML e HTML, totalmente abertos e sob ambiente totalmente padronizado (ex. recomendações IETF e W3C), podemos chutar que 99% podem ser UTF-8.

As diversas nuâncias e contextos do tema UTF-8 são discutudas [nesta resposta a uma pergunta similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28404/4186).

Comment: Interessante mas parece-me descontextualizado.

Comment: O título, por si só, já é *off-topic*: *"Qual sua opinião?"*. Confira [Good subjective, Bad subjective](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective).

Comment: @brasofilo, correto, e posso editar a pergunta conforme o "put on hold" sugere... Mas o que editar? Eu inicialmente coloquei como titulo "Como garantir que configurações, trocas de dados, etc. respeitem o UTF-8?" mas achei o presente titulo mais direto. Será que mudano o título fica claro o objetivo: dicas de como o programador pode exigir de clientes e fornecedores o respeito ao padrão UTF8.

Comment: Eu sei que é descontextualizado... mas eu gostaria de ver as respostas.

Comment: A discussão é muito interessante, mas não sei se funciona como pergunta. Quando li pela primeira vez, com o título antigo, parecia mais um artigo/manifesto do que uma pergunta. Talvez uma formulação mais objetiva fosse "por que devemos usar UTF-8 em vez de outras codificações?", e as respostas serviriam como justificativa que os programadores poderiam usar junto a clientes, fornecedores e até chefes (que muitas vezes também causam problemas). Mas a pergunta está redigida como quase uma "chamada às armas", uma convocação para que nos revoltemos e não aceitemos mais usar outras encodings [cont.]

Comment: Eu não acho que exista solução objetiva para esse problema, além da conscientização. UTF-8 é um standard, e todo standard leva um tempo até "pegar" definitivamente. Os próprios browsers e editores de texto demoraram um pouco até adotarem UTF-8 como padrão. Isso sem falar no PHP, que por padrão não usa UTF-8, o que atrapalha muito. Enfim, só pelo tamanho dos meus comentários já dá para ver que é uma discussão que dá muito pano pra manga. Mas é adequada ao site? Que tal discutirmos isso no meta? Alguém se habilita a abrir o debate por lá?

Comment: Outra tentativa: [transformei a pergunta em resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28404/4186). Foi uma solução para não perder o texto (pronto tá salvo)... Agora posso pedir para todos: **POR FAVOR EDITEM (deletando partes inclusive) O TEXTO DA PERGUNTA A VONTADE**. Acho que boas idéias já estão aparecendo aqui nos comentários, é só colocar em prática... e eu sozinho não estou sabendo: tratemos como uma Wiki, na Wikipedia sempre chegam a um "texto de consenso".