# Por que deveriamos utilizar funções que começam por mb_?

Tags: php

Algumas vezes, surgem problemas no PHP em relação a algumas funções de string, por causa da condificação das mesmas.

Um exemplo, é o `strlen`.

```
$a = strlen('str');

$b = strlen('stré');

var_dump($a, $b); // Imprime 3 e 5
```

Veja no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/gGPSLP)

Como vemos, no caso de `$b`, foi impresso que o mesmo possui `5` caracteres, e não `4`.

Sei por experiência que para resolver isso deveriamos utilizar `mb_strlen`, que são funções `multbyte` do PHP.

Exemplo:

```
var_dump(mb_strlen('stré', 'utf-8')); // Imprime 4
```

- O que quer dizer exatamente esse `multibyte`?
- Como é muito comum o uso de `UTF-8` aqui no Brasil, sempre deveriamos utilizarmos as funções do tipo `mb_` ao invés das funções comuns para trabalhar com strings?
- Por que isso não é tratado (em relação as funções comuns para trabalhar com string) simplesmente alterando o `default_charset` no `php.ini`?

Comment: pq prefixo são legais :D haha. Pergunta importante +1.

Comment: Importante e ninguém respondeu ainda :\

Comment: Um site pode ter varias linguagens logo o tratamento e diferente, uft8 pode servir para 1 linguagem mas nao para outra, por exemplo o Iso e o que aguenta com mais letras codificadas, por isso e que o tal default_charset no php.ini nao funciona.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As funções PHP cuja nomenclatura inicia com "mb_" pertencem as funções [MBString](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

MB significa "Multibyte", ou seja, são funções para manipular strings multibyte.

Encodes como UTF8 são do tipo multibyte (múltiplos bytes). Na documentação oficial, consulte a lista de encodes suportados: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Exemplo prático

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('html_errors',FALSE);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);

define( 'CHARSET',   'UTF-8' );

ini_set( 'default_charset', CHARSET );

if( PHP_VERSION < 5.6 ){
    ini_set( 'mbstring.http_output', CHARSET );
    ini_set( 'mbstring.internal_encoding', CHARSET );
}

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . CHARSET );

/*
Retorna 6
Cada caracter "coração" está ocupando 3 bytes.
Caso queira contar a quantidade de bytes, strlen() é o mais indicado.
*/
echo strlen('I♥NY') . PHP_EOL . '<br />';

/*
Retorna 4
Caso queira contar a quantidade de caracteres, utilize a função equivalente em MBString 
*/
echo mb_strlen('I♥NY');


/*
Note que mesmo os caracteres latinos são multibyte
*/
echo strlen('ação') . PHP_EOL . '<br />';
echo mb_strlen('ação');
?>
```

Outro termo pouco utilizado para referir-se a caracteres multibyte é "variable-width encoding" (codificação de largura variável).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding

**Nota adicional**

Nem sempre se faz necessário usar funções mbstring. Um exemplo de caso, é quando sabe-se que uma determinada string não possui caracteres multibyte.

Exemplo:

```
echo strlen('123') . PHP_EOL . '<br />';
echo mb_strlen('123');
```

Como mostra o exemplo, nesse caso é desnecessário, no entanto, podemos nos aprofundar mais com outro exemplo numérico.

```
echo strlen('１２３') . PHP_EOL . '<br />';
echo mb_strlen('１２３');
```

Nesse exemplo, são números, porém, multibyte.

Há muitos sistemas bem desenvolvidos que "pensam" ser internacionalizados, porém a vasta maioria não faz nenhum teste com o mundo real, como se o termo global se resumisse ao continente americano e europeu.

Mais de 60% do planeta (árabes, gregos, russos, indianos, asiáticos) utiliza caracteres multibyte e cada idioma possui peculiaridades como esse exemplo dos números multibyte da tabela do idioma japonês.

Por isso, recomenda-se o uso das funções MBString caso queira construir um sistema que ofereça maior compatibilidade possível com os diversos encodes existentes.

Outra nota importante: UTF8 não é um encode compatível com todos os idiomas. E as funções MBString não limitam-se a UTF8.

Exemplo, os caracteres chineses são melhor suportados pelo encode Big5.
Há também o uso de UTF16 ou UTF32.

Todavia, mesmo para caracteres chineses, o UTF8 também é utilizado com certa segurança, pois é "raro" que os próprios chineses utilizem todos os ideogramas. São mais de 60 mil.

Comment: Para te dar uma moral no conteúdo, coloque aí: _Como é muito comum o uso de UTF-8 aqui no Brasil, sempre deveriamos utilizarmos as funções do tipo mb_ ao invés das funções comuns para trabalhar com strings?_

Comment: me dê uma moral aceitando, aí ganho facinho os 50 pontos. whahaha

Comment: preferi não comentar sobre uma região específica pois esse assunto é global

Comment: Mas a nossa região usa `UTF-8`. E eu queria saber se e importante usar `mb_` em tudo que for criar (validação de nomes e etc)

Comment: está descrito na resposta, independente da "nossa região" . O que vc não conseguiu entender na resposta?