# Como pegar um tamanho de String corretamente utilizando UTF8?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo alguns testes e percebi que quanto a string possui caracteres especiais é contado mais de um no `substr`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$string = "PAÇOCA";

echo strlen($string);
echo substr($string, 0, 3);
```

Deveria imprimir: `PAÇ` mas so imprime `PA`, agora se eu aumentar um tamanho de 3 para 4 imprime, e se eu tirar o `Ç` e colocar um `C`, ele conta corretamente, então pelo que eu percebo ele esta considerando o `Ç` como se fosse dois caracteres, como eu posso conta-los de forma corretamente?

já tentei utilizar o mb_string também. e o header com UTF8.

Comment: Pra mim funcionou: http://ideone.com/PRGNGR

Comment: conta a mesma coisa. converta assim  $string = "PAÇOCA"; $a = utf8_decode($string ) ; echo utf8_encode(substr($a , 0, 3));

Comment: funções mb_string bastam, desde que estejam configuradas pra UTF-8

Comment: Tá com cara de duplicada

Comment: `strlen()` retorna o número de bytes da string (se der sorte o número de caracteres), `mb_strlen()` retorna o número de caracteres da string.

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicada : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78308/por-que-deveriamos-utilizar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-que-come%C3%A7am-por-mb

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu acho que é mais relacionada, pq no caso ele tentou usar mb_ mas nao adiantou, e aquela não foca na configuração. Mas é uma boa indicação complementar

Comment: @Bacco é verdade. Mas talvez porque ele tivesse que passar o terceiro 4 parâmetro, né, rsrsrsrsrsrsrsrs.

Comment: Agora eu to pensando, utilizo substr em 80% do meu projeto, vou ter que modificar tudo o.O

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues se seu encoding for UTF, sim. Se for ISO, pode deixar o substr. E em situações que for operação de bytes, sempre substr  sem o mb_ (por exemplo, extrair coisas codificadas, ou binárias) - E veja o link que eu pus para as configurações do ini, é melhor do que mudar o internal_encoding em runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funções `mb_` bastam, mas precisa configurar para o encoding correto:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Aí o resultado é

```
$string = "PAÇOCA";

echo mb_strlen($string);            // 6
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 3);      // PAÇ
```

**Só que seu código tem que ter sido salvo em UTF-8 no editor/IDE também!**
Afinal de contas, você está fornecendo um valor literal no *source* que não é afetado pelas configurações do PHP em si.

Tome cuidado para não setar desnecessariamente outras configurações, para evitar se confundir. O ideal mesmo é acertar tudo no `php.ini`, se possível, e não no *runtime*.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Configurando no `php.ini`

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mbstring.configuration.php

Comment: É isso mesmo valeu!

Answer (score 5):

Sugiro atualizar as configurações. Ficaria assim:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_BR.UTF8');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF8'); 
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF8');

    $string = "PAÇOCA";
    echo strlen($string);
    echo '<br>';
    echo mb_substr($string, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Acrescentando o pequeno detalhe.

Na documentação do [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) o  Andreas Bur diz:

> Para obter uma subseqüência de caracteres UTF-8, eu recomendo
>   mb_substr

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
 $string = "PAÇOCA";

 echo strlen($string);
 echo mb_substr($string, 0, 3, 'UTF-8');
?>
```

Comment: Essa sintaxe tb está correta, só vale notar que esse 3o parametro só é recomendavel se for uma exceção, por exemplo um caso em que você precise de um encoding de uma fonte diferente do seu default (pra não ter que ficar usando em todos os mb_ do código, e se um dia mudar, não precisa alterar tudo de novo, somente o internal_encoding)