# Problema com decodificação de caracteres

Tags: php

Estou usando uma função para limitar a quantidade de caracteres que são mostrados, algo como isso:

```
 function blabla ($string, $maxSize) {
    if (strlen($string) > $maxSize)
                $string = substr($string, 0, $maxSize) . ' [...]';
            return $string;
}
```

Só que está retornando alguns caracteres bugados como: "título" fica "T�tulo", mas quando eu não uso a função a string vem normal,sem caracteres bugados. como posso resolver isso?

Estou usando isto no header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: De onde está vindo essa `$string`?

Comment: É a entrada função, vou editar pra esclarecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mb_substr()` ao invés de `substr()` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php). Uma excelente resposta em outro contexto, mas que se amolda ao seu questionamento: [Problema ao usar substr em texto com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8240/42307)

Comment: Por favor **sempre** procure se já não existe resposta para o problema e então favoreça as respostas existentes, no caso esta pergunta tem resposta aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8235/3635 então você deve sinalizar a pergunta como duplicata. Não somos um fórum de suporte, somos um Q&A e procuramos agregar conteudo, mas se algo for muito semelhante realmente não é recomendo ficar duplicando respostas. Recomendo que quando tiver tempo leia o Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, @guilherme-nascimento, mas eu respondi ao contexto, e o contexto da outra pergunta é diferente. Nesta o usuário **não sabe** que o problema é a função `substr()`, na que você menciona, ele sabe. Mais: a orientação do guia da comunidade para perguntas duplicadas é pra quem pergunta  [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Aliás, a equipe já disse que algumas duplicatas são viáveis [veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) Mas eu vou levar essa observação em conta. Abraço!

Comment: Só pra que fique claro: o problema não tem a ver com a resposta dada, `substr` não faz conversão de caracteres. Provavelmente tem mais problemas no código original do que isso. Se está corrompendo caracteres no meio da string, é problema de encoding. O máximo que o `mb_` muda no `substr` é a contagem certa ou errada de caracteres: http://ideone.com/bDFlhE  - e é por isso que eu fechei unilateralmente como duplicata da que tem a ver com o assunto certo, que é como lidar com encoding. Senão teria fechado da outra de `substr` e `mb_substr` já existente (que é similar a essa resposta aqui).

Comment: Na verdade a solução do ShutUpMagda funcionou perfeitamente, a encoding é utf8 tanto no html como no banco de dados.

Comment: Pois é, @ngthm4r3, e sua pergunta **NÃO ESTÁ DUPLICADA**, viu? Primeiro porque não era problema de codificação, mas de contagem de caracteres, depois porque a maneira como foi redigida pode ajudar alguém que tenha problemas usando `substr()` mas **que não saiba disso**.

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 não foi sobre isto o que eu disse, eu disse que esta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8240/3635 responde a sua pergunta, afinal explica sobre o utf8 e o uso de funções com o prefixo `mb_` ;)